# Cannot find --lept, Gosseract build in windows

Tags: go, mingw, tesseract, msys2

I want to use the library github.com/otiai10/gosseract. The things I've done so far are installing MSYS2, which also includes the installation of leptonica, tesseract-ocr, and gcc. However, I encountered the following error:

C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -llept: No such file or directory.

where I can find this lept?

this is the client.go code from gosseract

```
// #if __FreeBSD__ >= 10
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -L/usr/local/lib -llept -ltesseract
// #else
// #cgo CXXFLAGS: -std=c++0x
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -llept -ltesseract
```

Answer (score 1):

it's solved with edit the client.go in gosseract library to like this

```
// #if __FreeBSD__ >= 10
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -L/usr/local/lib -llibleptonica -ltesseract
// #else
// #cgo CXXFLAGS: -std=c++0x
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -llibleptonica -ltesseract
// #cgo CPPFLAGS: -Wno-unused-result
```

change the -llept to -llibleptonica